Could a quantum walk easily traverse Rush-Hour type puzzles?
I was staring at a Rush-Hour type puzzle recently and I began to wonder if any such puzzles are amenable to a continuous-time quantum walk. The entrance and exit vertex are well-defined; at each stage of the solution there are only a handful of available moves to be applied; you can get stuck in the middle without knowing it; progress is difficult to determine until the end.

Although when generalized, Rush-Hour is PSPACE-complete (implying that the total number of moves from start to end grows superpolynomially, lest the sequence of moves counts as an NP-certificate), perhaps small enough instances could be approachable with a quantum walk.
What would it take to show that Rush-Hour does or doesn't have the requisite structure suggestive of quick traversal with a quantum walk?  Similarly for Klotski-type puzzles?
Playing with this website, there may be the kind of structure useful for a quantum walk to tunnel through tight jams, but there are still a lot of cycles in the graph and it's hard to say.

I envision the walk progressing by partially SWAP'ping lattice points unoccupied with cars, edge coloring based on the generators, and trotterizing accordingly. Could Schrödinger's equation explore the graph exponentially faster than the diffusion equation?
